# angular2 Dragula css cursor grab/grabbing not working

Tags: dragula, ng2-dragula, angular-dragula

Angular 2.4.8, dragula 3.10.6, it seems the cursor styling for grabbing is not applying when dnd. any suggestions?

css is imported in the index.html as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me. I am using Angular Cli and i placed CSS file inside my `.angular-cli.json` file

```
  "styles": [
 "../node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css",
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import css in `style.css` too like below.

```
@import '../node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css';
```